# regular expression match does not work

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string **ABCD:10,20,,40;1/1;1/2,1/3,1/4** I want to split the string into the following parts:

ABCD               -- splited by :

10,20,,40          -- splited by ;

1/1                -- splited by ;

1/2,1/3,1/4        -- splited by ;

Why the following regular expression does not work for me ?

```
string txt = @"ABCD:10,20,,40;1/1;1/2,1/3,1/4";

Regex reg = new Regex(@"\b(?<test>\w+):(?<com>\w+);(?<p1>\w+);(?<p2>\w+)");
Match match = reg.Match(txt);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `,` and `/` character will not be matched by `\w`.  `\w` matches letters, numbers, and underscores only.

It's better to use `[^;]+` to get everything but `;`'s for what you are trying to do:

```
new Regex(@"\b(?<test>\w+):(?<com>[^;]+);(?<p1>[^;]+);(?<p2>[^;]+)");
```

I left the `test` capture group alone, assuming it would always be `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`.

Answer (score 1):

If your tokens can't contain `:` and `;` themselves, you could just split on the regex: `[:;]`